# SwiftUI Crash when calling scrollTo method when view is disappearing

Tags: swiftui, scrollview

I try to make my **ScrollView** fixed in a specific place, but the **scrollTo** method will cause the application to crash.
How to make the ScrollView stay in a fixed place?
I want to control the switching of views by MagnificationGesture to switch from one view to another.
But when Scroll() disappdars, the app crashs.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var tabCount:Int = 1
    @State var current:CGFloat = 1
    @State var final:CGFloat = 1
    
    var body: some View {
        let magni = MagnificationGesture()
            .onChanged(){ value in
                current = value

            }
            .onEnded { value in
                if current > 2 {
                    self.tabCount += 1
                }
                final = current + final
                current = 0
            }
        
        VStack {
            VStack {
                Button("ChangeView"){
                    self.tabCount += 1
                }
                if tabCount%2 == 0 {
                    Text("some text")
                }else {
                    Scroll(current: $current)
                }
            }
            Spacer()
            HStack {
                Color.blue
            }
            .frame(width: 600, height: 100, alignment: .bottomLeading)
        }
        .frame(width: 600, height: 400)
        .gesture(magni)

    }
}
```

This is ScrollView, I want it can appear and disappear. When MagnificationGesture is changing, scrollview can keep somewhere.

```
struct Scroll:View {
    @Binding var current:CGFloat
    
    let intRandom = Int.random(in: 1..<18)

    var body: some View {
        ScrollViewReader { proxy in
            HStack {
                
                Button("Foreword"){
                    proxy.scrollTo(9, anchor: .center)
                }
            }
            ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                HStack {
                    ForEach(0..<20) { item in
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25.0)
                            .frame(width: 100, height: 40)
                            .overlay(Text("\(item)").foregroundColor(.white))
                            .id(item)
                    }
                }
                .onChange(of: current, perform: { value in
                    proxy.scrollTo(13, anchor: .center)
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your crash error message?

Comment: works well for me on macos 12.beta, xcode 13.beta, target ios 14.7 and macCatalyst 12. Tested on macOS 12 and iPhone ios 14.7.

Comment: The error code: 
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x7c). 
More than ten times of zoom gestures are required to cause the application to crash.
I used the instruments tool to detect memory leaks, and it located ```proxy.scrollTo(13, anchor: .center)```

Comment: Can't reproduce it too (on xcode 12.5, ios 14.5-14.6)
If that attribute graph exception then removing `anchor: .center` may helps